# What is the best way to create azure function that can read excel sheet and convert the data into POCO to push into Azure Table?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-functions, epplus

I am creating an Azure function that can read an excel file and push the data to an azure table. I have researched and found the following options to proceed with the solution

1. Use EP Plus Package. There is no native method or functionality in this package to map sheet data to POCO but I have come across a few solutions to custom build one as per the requirements.
2. Use OLEDB Connection to query the sheet data.
3. Interop dll. But this is out of the question considering the deployment on cloud since it needs to have MS Office installed on the server.

Which one of the above approach would be more suitable for Azure cloud platform? Please let me know if there is any other way apart from the two mentioned above. Thanks.